# Count cells with comment in range google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I would like to count cells with comments in a range.
I'm using GDOC spreadsheet.

I tried COUNTIF function, but it does not allow us to take into account cells with comments.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any formula that already exists for this, but it would be easy to write a script to do this for you - have you looked into trying this?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to script it, Would you be able to provide some example, Thank you !

Comment: this is possible only via script

Comment: I don't believe there is any support for comments in Apps Script.  There is for notes.

Answer (score 1):

### You can count cells containing comments with the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive) method [Comments:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/list)

- If you do not have programming skills, you can perform your request with the incorporated **Try this API** feature.
- All you need is to insert the `fileId` of the document, and specify in `Fields` "**comments(anchor)**"
- When you click on "**EXECUTE**", you will retrieve a response containing the anchors, that is the positions of the comments. Each position corresponds to a cell, so the number of anchors gives you the number of cells containing comments.

[image]

[image]

- If you decide to acquire knowledge of [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), you will be able to automitize the counting process.